# Hover over div/image to fade out image and have text fade in, but hovering over text removes fade out of image. How to prevent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webkit

Using React and CSS.

I have my app set where I can hover over the image, and the image will fade to a darker image. Text then fades in over it. BUT, when I touch the text with my cursor, it removes the fade. Does anyone know how I can prevent this?

[image]

My JSX file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ProjectSquare(props) {
    // const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

    //function hello() {
    //    console.log("Mouse entered.");
    //}

    return (
        <a href={props.project.linkString} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>
                <div className="project-box">
                    <span className="project-text">foo</span>
                    <img src={props.project.imgString} alt={props.project.imgString} />
                </div>


        </a>
    );
}

export default ProjectSquare;
```

My CSS file:

```
.project-box {
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*background-position-x: -80px;*/
    /*background-color: #a14ff9;*/
}

.project-box img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(20%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.project-text {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(0);
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

}

.project-box:hover .project-text {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.project-box img {
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle if possible ?

Comment: `.project-box:hover img {...}` instead of `img:hover`? Or another solution `pointer-events:none;` for `.project-text`

Comment: @Medi It's on a local machine. It might take a minute to get it working on there. I'll try to get it working for you

Comment: Try this first if it work before `.project-box img:hover, .project-box .project-text img:hover` replace it with `.project-box img:hover`.

Comment: @dw_ Thank you! `pointer-events:none;` worked!

Comment: @Medi Thank you for your help as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Make anchor tag a block element, and add hover to `.project-box` not `img`.

```css
a.project-box-anchor {
  /* anchor tag added inline-block */
  display: inline-block;
}

.project-box {
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*background-position-x: -80px;*/
    /*background-color: #a14ff9;*/
}

/* instead of hovering on image, hover on the whole project box */
.project-box:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(20%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.project-text {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(0);
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

}

.project-box:hover .project-text {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.project-box img {
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a class="project-box-anchor" href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
  <div class="project-box">
    <span class="project-text">foo</span>
    <img style="height:100px;" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt="alt_text" />
  </div>
</a>
```

**Solution 2:** More "hacky"

```
.project-text {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```